# error: cannot find symbol class DaggerAppComponent version conflict with other dependencies

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I am getting "error: cannot find symbol class DaggerAppComponent" while building android project 
,i changed the version of dagger and other dependencies to latest one and i tired older version also
but still getting same error.

My build.gradle file

```
 // ButterKnife libraries
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0'

// Dagger 2 libraries


implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"

// Components for Android
implementation group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.2.0-alpha01'

// Networking
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.6.2'

// gogole support design
implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0'

// Lombok for pojo
implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'

//Rx java and Rx android
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'

//Realm local DB
implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.2.0'

//SmileyRating Bar
implementation 'com.github.sujithkanna:smileyrating:1.6.8'
```

Comment: Where are you seeing the error? Can you show the class.

Comment: Try commenting out the line that calls DaggerAppComponent and 'Clean', then 'Make Project' from the build menu. Then uncomment the line.

Answer (score -1):

Here i am getting the error cannot find symbol class DaggerAppComponent

```
 public class Injector {

    // Singleton instance
    private static Injector instance;

    // components
    private AppComponent appComponent;

    // Private constructor to make it singleton
    private Injector() {
    }

    /**
     * Get the singleton Injector instance
     *
     * @return Injector
     */
    private static Injector instance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Injector();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * Creates application component which is used of injection later.
     *
     * @param application
     */
    public static void createApplicationComponent(Application application) {
        if (instance().appComponent == null) {
            instance().appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                    .appModule(new AppModule(application))
                    .build();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the component for injection.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static AppComponent component() {
        return instance().appComponent;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be edited into your question not as an answer @Anand Mgmsa